# Чи має запозичений термін "комп'ютер" синоніми українського походження?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни, синоніми

Пошук у словниках синонімів [тут](http://www.rozum.org.ua), [тут](http://www.hohlopedia.org.ua/use_universalnyy_slovnyk_entsyklopediya/search/?word=&select=slovnyk_synonimiv_karavanskogo) і [тут](https://xn--h1aaldafs6o.xn--j1amh/%D0%9A/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF'%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80) результатів не дає.
У [вікісловнику](https://uk.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF'%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80) не вказано жодного синоніму, а у [вікіпедії](https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF'%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80) вказано синонімом абревіатуру «**ЕОМ**», яка використовується як правовий термін в юридичних документах, інженерами цифрової електроніки, також в історичному сенсі — для позначення комп'ютерної техніки 1940-1980-х років, і для позначення великих обчислювальних пристроїв, на відміну від персональних.
У цьому [джерелі](http://www.m-translate.com.ua/en-uk/word-computer-translation) вказано ще декілька синонімів: **компутор**, **лічильник**, **обчислювальна техніка**, **обчислювач**. Чи є якийсь з цих термінів сталим? Чи можливо його використання на заміну запозиченому **комп'ютер**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Компутор** - точно не те що ви шукаєте, оскільки має те ж саме походження що і **комп'ютер**.

**Обчислювальна техніка** використовується зараз для загального позначення всіх пристроїв що виконують програмовані обчислення, не обов'язково персональні комп'ютери - бортові комп'ютери, мікрокомп'ютери вбудовані в побутову техніку і таке інше.

**Лічильник** - вже також має стале значення. Це простий пристрій що, наприклад, у побуті рахує споживання ресурсів (газу, опалення, води). У комп'ютерній техніці це базова "комірка" що вміє збільшувати значення на одиницю:

> 1. Той, хто веде лік чому-небудь.
> 2. Прилад для підраховування чого-небудь. В ній [ракеті] є два передавачі з антенами, лічильник космічного проміння (Наука і життя, 2, 1959, 7); Він не відривав очей од лічильника [таксі].. Його зацікавила сама механіка — диви, як блискають цифри, як швидко росте сума (Юрій Збанацький, Курилові о-ви, 1963, 37);  * Образно. І став Біг-Бен, вусач-солдат, лічильником годин (Микола Бажан, Роки, 1957, 183).

**Обчислювач** до появи комп'ютерів так називався працівник, що виконує обчислення. З появою електронних систем їх називали **електронними обчислювачами**:

> ОБЧИ́СЛЮВАЧ, а, чол.
>   1. Працівник, який обробляє числові дані. Створено електронно-рахівничу машину, яка за вісім годин викопує роботу 15 тисяч кваліфікованих розраховувачів і обчислювачів (Колгоспник України, 11, 1957, 40); Стоїш, чергуєш, в напрузі вдивляєшся в сітку прозорого плексигласового планшета, на якій сержант-обчислювач щораз виводить все нові й нові цифрові позначки (Олесь Гончар, Тронка, 1963, 294).
>   2. Прилад, апарат, який обробляє числові дані. Електронний обчислювач.

Думаю що це слово в принципі ще якось можна притягнути до значення "комп'ютер", хоча, швидше за все, як термін воно може позначати пристрій який не має повного набору функцій які має повноцінний комп'ютер. Не дарма в той самий час з'явився термін Електронна обчислювальна машина, яка вочевидь мала більше можливостей ніж простий електронний обчислювач (фактично різниця між ними як між комп'ютером та калькулятором).

Answer (score 7):

Є два варіанти для слова комп’ютер на [словотворі](http://slovotvir.org.ua): "обчислювач" і "рахівник".

Так, словотвір не є авторитетним джерелом, тому наводжу декілька прикладів зі слов’янських і не тільки мов:

1. В івриті є слово "מחשב" /махшев/ (від לחשב /лєхашев/ - обчислювати), і вони користуються саме ним, а не словом комп’ютер;
2. В чеській є слово "počítač";
3. В словенській - računalnik;
4. В хорватській - "računalo".

Ґуґл-перекладач свідчить про використання хорватами, словенами й чехами саме цих відповідників, а не "загальновживаного" комп’ютер.

Таким чином, слова "рахівник" і "обчислювач" водночас передають зміст слова "computer" і досить органічно звучать українською.

Comment: В іспанській використовується іменник "ordenador", утворений від дієслова "ordenar" - організовувати/впорядковувати/наказувати/давати команду. Щоправда, слово "computador(a)" - "комп'ютер" в них теж є у словнику. В німецькій є іменник "Rechner", утворений від дієслова "rechnen" - обчислювати/рахувати.

Answer (score 2):

Етимологія [to compute](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compute) у вікісловнику каже нам:

> (17th century). Borrowing from French computer, from Latin computare ‎(“sum up, reckon, compute”), from com ‎(“together”) + putare ‎(“cleanse, trim, prune, clear up, settle, adjuct, reckon, count, deem, think, suppose”), from putus ‎(“cleansed, clear”)

Тобто з[(*у/в*)важувач](http://sum.in.ua/s/uvazhaty) можна важати дослівним перекладом. Але

1. нажаль я не можу підважити цю думку посиланням на авторитетні джерела чи відомі використання
2. Це слово від кальки російського `взвешиватель` відрізняється лише одним звуком, який наврядчи буде чітко артикулюватися при усному мовленні

Answer (score 1):

*Комп’ютер* - від англ. *to compute* - *обчислювати*, тому *електронно-обчислювальна машина* є абсолютним точним перекладом.

Відомих синонімів у слова *комп'ютер* немає, є лише сленгові назви - *пісюк*, *пісі*, *персоналка* (від *personal computer*або *PC*).

Також *комп'ютери* еволюціонували в *сервери*, *планшети*, *трансформери* (десктоп + планшет), проте в загальному вигляді *комп'ютер* є загальновживаним і зрозумілим для більшості людей терміном.